# R - reformat P value in ggplot using 'stat_compare_means'

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I want to plot the p values to each panel in a faceted ggplot. If the p value is larger than 0.05, I want to display the p value as it is. If the p value is smaller than 0.05, I want to display the value in scientific notation (i.e, 0.0032 -> 3.20e-3; 0.0000425 -> 4.25e-5).

The code I wrote to do this is:

```r
   p1 <- ggplot(data = CD3, aes(location, value, color = factor(location),
                             fill = factor(location))) + 
  theme_bw(base_rect_size = 1) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3, size = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#4cdee6", "#e47267", "#13ec87")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4cdee6", "#e47267", "#13ec87")) +
  ylab(expression(paste("Density of clusters, ", mm^{-2}))) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("CT", 'N'), c("IF","N")), 
                     aes(label = ifelse(..p.format.. < 0.05, formatC(..p.format.., format = "e", digits = 2),
                                        ..p.format..)), 
                     method = 'wilcox.test', show.legend = FALSE, size = 10) +
  #ylab(expression(paste('Density, /', mm^2, )))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 38), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 40), 
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white", size = 2),
        strip.text = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10), size = 40),
        panel.grid = element_line(size = 1.5))
plot(p1)
```

This code runs without error, however, the format of numbers isn't changed. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
I attached the data to reproduce the plot: [donwload data here](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/ES2j1tWul2NJhqeQAmP4AbIBqQZLK3dS0mhNlITwwLDaow?e=tH16aO)

**EDIT**

```
structure(list(value = c(0.931966449207829, 3.24210526315789, 
3.88811650210901, 0.626860993574675, 4.62085308056872, 0.477508650519031, 
0.111900110501359, 3.2495164410058, 4.06626506024096, 0.21684918139434, 
1.10365086026018, 4.66666666666667, 0.174109967855698, 0.597625869832174, 
2.3758865248227, 0.360751947840548, 1.00441501103753, 3.65168539325843
), Criteria = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Density", "Density of cluster", 
"nodular count", "Elongated count"), class = "factor"), Case = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("Case 1A", "Case 1B", "Case 2", "Case 3", "Case 4", 
"Case 5"), class = "factor"), Mark = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CD3", 
"CD4", "CD8", "CD20", "FoxP3"), class = "factor"), location = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("CT", "IF", "N"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(91L, 
92L, 93L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 166L, 167L, 168L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please include example data in the body of your question instead of linking to external data, for reasons see: http://bitly.com/98K8eH

Comment: I presume this is stat_compare_means from `ggpubr`? Please include the library calls necessary to run your code.

Comment: Yes the function is from ggpubr. The reason I attached a link is that the data is quite large. I will try to attach a snippet of the data in the body.

Comment: Thank you. It's most helpful to include the output of `dput(SAMPLE_OF_DATA)` so that we can directly recreate your data object. (Multiple forms of data can print the same way, so the printed appearance is less specific & helpful.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue came from the `stat_compare_means` and the use of `comparisons`. 
I'm not totally sure, but I will guess that the output of p value for `stat_compare_means` is different from `compare_means` and so, you can't use it for the `aes` of `label`.

Let me explain, with your example, you can modify the display of the p.value like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(df, aes(x = location, y = value, color = location))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_compare_means(ref.group = "N", aes(label = ifelse(p < 0.05,sprintf("p = %2.1e", as.numeric(..p.format..)), ..p.format..)))
```

[image]

You get the correct display of p.value but you lost your bars. So, if you use `comparisons` argument, you get:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(df, aes(x = location, y = value, color = location))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("CT","N"), c("IF","N")), aes(label = ifelse(p < 0.05,sprintf("p = %2.1e", as.numeric(..p.format..)), ..p.format..)))
```

[image]

So, now, you get bars but not the correct display.

To circumwent this issue, you can perform the statistics outside of ggplot2 using `compare_means` functions and use the package `ggsignif` to display the correct display.

Here, I'm using `dplyr` and the function `mutate` to create new columns, but you can do it easily in `base` R.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
c <- compare_means(value~location, data = df, ref.group = "N")
c %<>% mutate(y_pos = c(5,5.5), labels = ifelse(p < 0.05, sprintf("%2.1e",p),p))

# A tibble: 2 x 10
  .y.   group1 group2       p p.adj p.format p.signif method   y_pos labels 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  
1 value N      CT     0.00866 0.017 0.0087   **       Wilcoxon   5   8.7e-03
2 value N      IF     0.00866 0.017 0.0087   **       Wilcoxon   5.5 8.7e-03
```

Then, you can plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggsignif)
ggplot(df, aes(x = location, y = value))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = location))+
  ylim(0,6)+
  geom_signif(data = as.data.frame(c), aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=labels, y_position=y_pos),
                manual = TRUE)
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to plot ?

Comment: Excellent! This looks like exactly what I want! However, when I trying to reproduce this result from my end, it tells me xmin, xmax, annotations, and y_position are unknown aesthetics. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, I have the same warning but it does not prevent to get the plot. Do you get the plot ? On this post, there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763582/ggplot-and-ggsignif-error-on-grouping-variable. It did not change anything for me.

Comment: Hello, do you know how to make appear a "p = " before the p-values?

Comment: After creating `df`, you can modify the labels columns by doing: `df$labels <- paste0("p = ",df$labels)`