# stat_compare_means conditional p-value labels causes ggplot fill to fail

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following the example of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494698/r-reformat-p-value-in-ggplot-using-stat-compare-means) I aim to only label the comparisons if the p-value is below a certain threshold. After finally getting it to work I see it is offsetting the previously set ggplot parameters and no longer able to find the fill variable.

I have included a reproducible example and my desired output.

```
set.seed(20)
col1<-c(rep('E', each = 8))
col2<-c(rep('R', each = 8))
col3<-c(rep('S', each = 8))
behaviour<-c(col1,col2,col3)
value <- runif(length(behaviour), min=2, max=8)
shannon <- c(rep('Shannon', each = length(behaviour)))
test.data <- data.frame(behaviour, value, shannon)

d <- compare_means(value~behaviour, data = test.data,method = 't.test')
d %<>% mutate(y_pos = c(5,5.5,6),labels = ifelse(p<0.17,p.format,p.signif))

d
.y. group1  group2  p   p.adj   p.format    p.signif    method  y_pos   labels
value   E   R   0.4678791   0.76    0.47    ns          T-test  5.0     ns
value   E   S   0.1559682   0.47    0.16    ns          T-test  5.5     0.16
value   R   S   0.3794209   0.76    0.38    ns          T-test  6.0     ns


shannonviolin<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x = behaviour, y = value)) +
  labs(y= "Shannon",color = " ",size=8)+
  geom_violin(position=position_dodge(width=1.2),alpha = 0.7,scale="width",adjust=0.9,trim=FALSE)+ 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.4,outlier.colour = "transparent")+
  geom_point(aes(fill = behaviour), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("E" = '#3797a4', "R"= '#96bb7c',"S"= '#944e6c'))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()
        )+
ylim(0, 14)

shannonviolin+geom_signif(data = as.data.frame(d), tip_length = 0.01, aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=labels,y_position=c(12.4,13,13.6)),manual=TRUE)
```

This is getting it to work:

[image]

But there is no fill colour. If I specify fill parameter inside ggplot:

```
shannonviolinfill<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x = behaviour, y = value,fill=behaviour)) +
  labs(y= "Shannon",color = " ",size=8)+
  geom_violin(position=position_dodge(width=1.2),alpha = 0.7,scale="width",adjust=0.9,trim=FALSE)+ 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.4,outlier.colour = "transparent")+
  geom_point(aes(fill = behaviour), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("E" = '#3797a4', "R"= '#96bb7c',"S"= '#944e6c'))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()
        )+
ylim(0, 14)
shannonviolinfill+geom_signif(data = as.data.frame(d), tip_length = 0.01, aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=labels,y_position=c(12.4,13,13.6)),manual=TRUE)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill
```

Ideally it should look like this:

[image]

If anyone knows a hack or a workaround I'd greatly appreciate it as I've been circling the drain all day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you made `fill = behaviour` a global aes. However, there is no column named `behaviour` in your dataset `d`. As a workaround make it local by removing it from `ggplot()` and instead use `aes(fill = behaviour)` in both `geom_violin` and `geom_boxcplot`:

```r
set.seed(20)
col1<-c(rep('E', each = 8))
col2<-c(rep('R', each = 8))
col3<-c(rep('S', each = 8))
behaviour<-c(col1,col2,col3)
value <- runif(length(behaviour), min=2, max=8)
shannon <- c(rep('Shannon', each = length(behaviour)))
test.data <- data.frame(behaviour, value, shannon)


library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

d <- compare_means(value~behaviour, data = test.data,method = 't.test')
d %<>% mutate(y_pos = c(5,5.5,6),labels = ifelse(p<0.17,p.format,p.signif))


shannonviolin<-ggplot(test.data, aes(x = behaviour, y = value)) +
  labs(y= "Shannon",color = " ",size=8)+
  geom_violin(aes(fill = behaviour), position=position_dodge(width=1.2),alpha = 0.7,scale="width",adjust=0.9,trim=FALSE)+ 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = behaviour), width=0.4,outlier.colour = "transparent")+
  geom_point(aes(fill = behaviour), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("E" = '#3797a4', "R"= '#96bb7c',"S"= '#944e6c'))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()
  )+
  ylim(0, 14)

shannonviolin+geom_signif(data = as.data.frame(d), tip_length = 0.01, aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=labels,y_position=c(12.4,13,13.6)),manual=TRUE)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, annotations, y_position
#> Warning: Removed 141 rows containing missing values (geom_violin).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry one more question. What IDE do you use to run R? Your plots are far superior resolution to mine. I'm using jupyter notebook.

Comment: I'm using RStudio. And as of the moment on a Mac. But when I'm on my Windows machine my plots don't look great too in RStudio. (;